# MongoDB upgrade 2.4 to 2.6 check returns error in internal collections

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I have a replica set and want to upgrade MongoDB from version 2.4.5 to 2.6.1 and before replacing binaries use this command: `db.upgradeCheckAllDBs()`

However this error returns:

```
...

Checking collection local.replset.minvalid
Document Error: document is no longer valid in 2.6 because DollarPrefixedFieldName: $set is not valid for storage.: {  "_id" : ObjectId("50101a875b51c70037b81c30"),  "ts" : Timestamp(1398232884, 51),  "h"
 : NumberLong("4590312020654652586"),  "op" : "u",  "ns" : "jumbo.jumboFile2Upload",  "o2" : {  "_id" : ObjectId("510b039031c82133929bd77f") },  "o" : {  "$set" : {  "operation" : {  "operation" : "upload
",  "total" : NumberLong(1048768),  "done" : NumberLong(671576) } } } }

...

To fix the problems above please consult http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/upgrade_checker_help
false
```

This error is in internal MongoDB collection (`local.replset.minvalid`). Mentioned [link](http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/upgrade_checker_help) states:

> To resolve, remove the document and re-insert with the appropriate
>   corrections.

What does this `local.replset.minvalid` do? I do not feel comfortable updating internal MongoDB collections.

This collection `local.replset.minvalid` contains only one document:

```
set0:PRIMARY> db.replset.minvalid.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("50101a875b51c70037b81c30"),
        "ts" : Timestamp(1398232884, 51),
        "h" : NumberLong("4590312020654652586"),
        "op" : "u",
        "ns" : "jumbo.jumboFile2Upload",
        "o2" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("510b039031c82133929bd77f")
        },
        "o" : { 
                "$set" : {
                        "operation" : {
                                "operation" : "upload",
                                "total" : NumberLong(1048768),
                                "done" : NumberLong(671576)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Any suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it is a minor [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14092) that will be solved in new version and can be ignored during upgrade in my case. I did the upgrade and everything works as expected.